# Synonym for "turd"

Tags: slang, politeness, medical

Is there a countable noun with the exact same meaning as "turd" - a single, formed piece of faecal matter?
Giving the reason for this enquiry might illustrate why 'stool' doesn't really work IMO.

(1) I have an infestation of small animals in my lawn, resulting in numerous small holes about 1" in diameter. I discovered that they could be discouraged from perforating the greensward by using a trowel to stuff a firm dog turd down each hole, then covering it with a handful of earth.

(2) I was imagining how to explain the process of rolling a cigarette. My preferred method is to roll a paper into a cylinder, using a 9/32" drill as the core to roll around. After inserting a filter into one end, I roll a small quantity of tobacco into an elongated ball the size and shape of a mouse turd. This is dropped into the open end of the cylinder ready to be gently compacted by a toothpick.

I suppose 'dropping' might be a suitably ambiguous term to use in the latter case, but I can't really accept 'a stool' as the product of canine bowel evacuation.

Comment: 'Stool' is the obvious candidate. It would be used in formal, medical etc settings, unlike the rather offensive 'turd'. But have you looked up 'turd' in dictionaries / thesauri?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “A turd by any other name would smell…”

Comment: @David It's bad enough falling between two stools.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're looking for a slang term, a polite term, or a medical term. It's also unclear why you've rejected "turd" and "stool".

Comment: @AndyT 
I originally wrote that I was looking for a polite term, but this seems to have disappeared in my confusion. I think you'll agree that a !'dog stool' doesn't sound right.

I also added the 'politeness' tag to indicate that I was looking for a polite alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an 'answer' here because it is not that easy to ascertain whether **stool** is actually used in count usages.

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stool) has:

> **stool** [noun] [countable] ...
>
> 2a *piece of solid waste from someone’s body*
>
> Synonyms and related words:
>
> [Human and animal waste]: cowpat, crap, dog dirt...

While 'cowpat' is count, the other 'synonyms/related words' are almost invariably not.

I'd say that the bare noun 'stools' is the most commonly used form (as opposed to a stool or umpteen stools), in a way closely synonymous with non-count plural-form 'faeces/feces'.

But indisputably count usages can be found, for example:

> He has slept considerably since he was bled, and during the night; he
>   has had only three stools last night, the last of which is scanty and
>   serous; the pulse is 80 ...

[[Practical treatises on tropical and scorbutic dysentery; on some ...
By RW Bampfield](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bxBgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=%22only+three+stools%22&source=bl&ots=Z1i3DRKDYv&sig=ACfU3U2FsGg_4r6DHkAJEDT-YfOoYIfkZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc9uGyn4rmAhX0TxUIHVAKAFMQ6AEwFnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22only%20three%20stools%22&f=false)] (admittedly from 1826).

> ... with the diarrhea practically resolving by the third day of treatment
>   with gelatin tannate (only three stools of almost normal consistency) ...

[[Case Reports in Gastrointestinal Medicine_PMC US National Library of Medicine
National Institutes of Health 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3350249/)].

'Stools' for faeces is common, but the obviously-count plural usage (a plural-form  usage with a numeral or equivalent) and 'a stool' ('a' does not always confirm a count usage, but probably would here), I'd say, pretty rare. The situation is (usually) etically count, but who's counting?

Comment: Is there a difference between American and British English here? I can't imagine replacing *turd* with *stool* in *there are goose turds all over the lawn*,  and the definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stool)  for *stool*: "a discharge of fecal matter," fits with your quotes, but not with "goose stools". On the other hand, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stool) defines *stool* as "a piece of faeces," which is exactly the definition that the OP wants.

Comment: In my experience, we'd rarely use a countifiable noun, never mind a count usage. 'Dogmuck' / 'catmuck' / 'birdmuck' / 'birdshit'; 'horse manure'. Probably, on the odd occasion, 'goose/pigeon ... droppings' (but I've never heard a numeral used).   As I say, who's counting? Perhaps 'several cowpats'. The medical people may of course need to quantify, and hereabouts I've heard the count (or at least plural-form) usage of 'stool'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth

"... we'd rarely use a countifiable noun ..." Agreed, but in the two cases I mentioned I really need a singular form like 'turd.' Other languages have them.

Comment: The only thing I can think of between the formal 'stool' and the vulgar slang 'turd' is 'piece of excrement'. I've checked in a couple of thesauri.  English has lacunas.